# I try to access my desktop thru my PowerShell, and its said "Cannot find path 'C:\Desktop' because it does not exist"

Tags: powershell, terminal, path, com, desktop

how can I fix this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMzNy.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Desktop` is a special folder and to get the path to it, you can use

```
Set-Location ([environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop'))
```

<sup>`cd` is an alias to the `Set-Location` cmdlet</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You have to go into your user directory and access it from there. Something like:

```
cd C:\Users\mfi\Desktop
```

mfi is the User in my case and you can access the desktop from there.